# How to configure http request with "form" in elm

Tags: http, frontend, elm

I just started learning elm this week so excuse me if the question is super basic.

So, I want to send a keyword (which is part of my Model, as shown in the forms example at https://elm-lang.org/examples/forms) as a "form" from my elm frontend to my backend. My cURL HTTP request looks like this:

`curl -X 'POST' --form 'keyword=key' 0.0.0.0:5000/search`

How would I transform that into an HTTP request written in elm, specifically the `--form` part? I read the HTTP section in the elm guide, but it doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: I think you need to construct the body of your post request using [multipartBody](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#multipartBody)

Comment: @5ndG Thanks, could you explain why it should be multipartBody instead of just stringBody? I tried stringBody but it didn't work.

Comment: It's because your backend is expecting a form, so multipartBody will format the request correctly so the backend will understand it.

Answer (score 5):

`--form` corresponds to a multipart request, which you can use [Http.multipartBody](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#multipartBody) to construct. This is the equivalent of your example curl request.

```
Http.post
    { url = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/search"
    , body =
        Http.multipartBody
            [ Http.stringPart "keyword" "key"
            ]
    , expect = Http.expectString GotText
    }
```

With a `multipartBody` you can also post files and blobs with [`filePart`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#filePart) and [`bytesPart`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#bytesPart), respectively, in addition to simple key-value pairs as done here using [`stringPart`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#stringPart)

Comment: Thank you so much!! Since my backend actually sends a JSON file, should the last line be `expect = Http.expectJson GotJson (Json.Decode.list string)` instead?

Comment: It doesn't have to, since you can decode the string manually as well, but it would certainly be a lot more convenient, yes!